# Вход с аккаунтом Google временно заблокирован

Tags: google-account, google-plus

Многие из пользователей моего сервиса, используют для авторизации аккаунт Google. Вся печаль в том, что они сталкиваются с ошибкой такого вида.

[image: В Приложение нельзя войти так как оно ещё не прошло нашу проверку]

Всё бы ничего, но в кабинете разработчика приложение одобрено.

[image: Приложение одобрено в кабинете разработчика]

Подтверждение прав не требуется так как проверка проходилась ранее и успешно, приложение было одобрено, вот только пользователи так и получают предупреждение.

Даже я сам, как администратор, если удалю из аккаунта гугл (profile.google.com) доступ к приложению, более не смогу авторизоваться через приложение всё из-за той же ошибки). Как можно решить данный вопрос?